# How to fix _TypeError (type 'List<Animal?>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Animal>?' of 'value')

Tags: flutter, dart

I am unable to understand what's wrong with my code. Whatever I try I am still getting this error when trying to confirm my selection in multiselect widget.
Here's my code.

```
class _ParticipantsToSelectState extends State<ParticipantsToSelect> {
  static List<Animal> _animals = [
    Animal(id: 1, name: "Lion"),
    Animal(id: 2, name: "Flamingo"),
    Animal(id: 3, name: "Hippo"),
    Animal(id: 4, name: "Horse"),
    Animal(id: 5, name: "Tiger"),
    Animal(id: 6, name: "Penguin"),
    Animal(id: 7, name: "Spider"),
    Animal(id: 8, name: "Snake"),
    Animal(id: 9, name: "Bear"),
    Animal(id: 10, name: "Beaver"),
  ];

  final _items = _animals
      .map((animal) => MultiSelectItem<Animal>(animal, animal.name))
      .toList();
  List<Animal?>? _selectedAnimals3 = [];
  final _multiSelectKey = GlobalKey<FormFieldState<List<Animal>?>>(); // Update here

  @override
  void initState() {
    _selectedAnimals3 = _animals;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: MultiSelectBottomSheetField<Animal>(
        key: _multiSelectKey,
        initialChildSize: 0.7,
        maxChildSize: 0.95,
        title: Text("Animals"),
        buttonText: Text("Favorite Animals"),
        items: _items,
        searchable: true,
        validator: (values) {
          if (values == null || values.isEmpty) {
            return "Required";
          }
          List<String> names = values.map((e) => e!.name).toList(); // Update here
          if (names.contains("Frog")) {
            return "Frogs are weird!";
          }
          return null;
        },
        onConfirm: (List<Animal?>? values) { // Update here
          setState(() {
            _selectedAnimals3 = values;
          });
          _multiSelectKey.currentState?.validate();
        },
        chipDisplay: MultiSelectChipDisplay(
          onTap: (item) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedAnimals3!.remove(item);
            });
            _multiSelectKey.currentState?.validate();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to cast _selectedAnimals3 and also 'values' and then initialize it with _animals but getting the same error. I need to get _selectedAnimals3 populated with selected items when confirming it.

Comment: Let me ask you, what do you think the difference between `List<Animal?>` and `List<Animal>?` is?

Comment: Also, why did you declare `_selectedAnimals3` as a nullable reference? It is initialized to a non-null value and your `onConfirm` method doesn't _need_ to replace the entire collection, you could just clear it.

Comment: So, List<Animal?> means a list of objects of type Animal that can have null values, whereas List<Animal>? means a nullable list of objects of type Animal, which can be either a list of objects of type Animal or a null value.

Comment: Right, so why do you say you don't understand what's wrong with your code?

Comment: Actually I started with List<Animal> _selectedAnimals3 = []; and
but I guess it was wrong ? Can you suggest what should be the lines for declaration and onConfirm ?

Comment: This was my initial.declaration and onConfirm that threw the same error.List<Animal> _selectedAnimals3 = [];
onConfirm: (values) {
          setState(() {
            _selectedAnimals3 = values
                .where((element) => element != null)
                .toList()
                .cast<Animal>();
          });
          _multiSelectKey.currentState?.validate();
        },

Comment: Your `onConfirm` method does not need to overwrite `_selectedAnimals3` on `null` arguments - just clear the existing list if `values` is `null`.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response but could you please suggest the code for clearing the existing list ?

Comment: Uh... `.clear()` ?

Comment: Sorry I don't get. If I use clear() it's going to clear the entire list, no ? I want _selectedAnimals3 to keep selected items.

Comment: So what is `onConfirm` _meant_ to do with `values` then?

Comment: It should populate _selectedAnimals3 list with selected values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue on this library for long back, to avoid this issue, you should make `MultiSelectBottomSheetField<Animal?>` type parameter as nullable.

Your code should be like as following

```dart
class _ParticipantsToSelectState extends State<ParticipantsToSelect> {
  static final List<Animal> _animals = [
    Animal(id: 1, name: "Lion"),
    Animal(id: 2, name: "Flamingo"),
    Animal(id: 3, name: "Hippo"),
    Animal(id: 4, name: "Horse"),
    Animal(id: 5, name: "Tiger"),
    Animal(id: 6, name: "Penguin"),
    Animal(id: 7, name: "Spider"),
    Animal(id: 8, name: "Snake"),
    Animal(id: 9, name: "Bear"),
    Animal(id: 10, name: "Beaver"),
  ];

  final _items = _animals.map((animal) => MultiSelectItem<Animal>(animal, animal.name)).toList();
  List<Animal?> _selectedAnimals3 = [];
  final _multiSelectKey = GlobalKey<FormFieldState<List<Animal>>>(); // Update here

  @override
  void initState() {
    _selectedAnimals3 = _animals;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: MultiSelectBottomSheetField<Animal?>(
        key: _multiSelectKey,
        initialChildSize: 0.7,
        maxChildSize: 0.95,
        title: const Text("Animals"),
        buttonText: const Text("Favorite Animals"),
        items: _items,
        searchable: true,
        validator: (values) {
          if (values == null || values.isEmpty) {
            return "Required";
          }
          List<String> names = values.map((e) => e!.name).toList(); // Update here
          if (names.contains("Frog")) {
            return "Frogs are weird!";
          }
          return null;
        },
        onConfirm: (List<Animal?> values) {
          // Update here
          setState(() {
            _selectedAnimals3 = values;
          });
          _multiSelectKey.currentState?.validate();
        },
        chipDisplay: MultiSelectChipDisplay(
          onTap: (item) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedAnimals3.remove(item);
            });
            _multiSelectKey.currentState?.validate();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I suggest you to find some other library to achieve your requirement.

**Edited**

I have forked the library to solve this issue.
I have seen there are multiple PRs under review, looks developer is inactive.

Add change the `pubspecs.yaml` with following line

```
  multi_select_flutter:
    git: https://github.com/alexsunderlion/multi_select_flutter.git
```

And you code should be as following.

```
class _ParticipantsToSelectState extends State<ParticipantsToSelect> {
  static final List<Animal> _animals = [
    Animal(id: 1, name: "Lion"),
    Animal(id: 2, name: "Flamingo"),
    Animal(id: 3, name: "Hippo"),
    Animal(id: 4, name: "Horse"),
    Animal(id: 5, name: "Tiger"),
    Animal(id: 6, name: "Penguin"),
    Animal(id: 7, name: "Spider"),
    Animal(id: 8, name: "Snake"),
    Animal(id: 9, name: "Bear"),
    Animal(id: 10, name: "Beaver"),
  ];

  final _items = _animals.map((animal) => MultiSelectItem<Animal>(animal, animal.name)).toList();
  List<Animal> _selectedAnimals3 = [];
  final _multiSelectKey = GlobalKey<FormFieldState<List<Animal>>>(); // Update here

  @override
  void initState() {
    _selectedAnimals3 = _animals;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: MultiSelectBottomSheetField<Animal>(
        key: _multiSelectKey,
        initialChildSize: 0.7,
        maxChildSize: 0.95,
        title: const Text("Animals"),
        buttonText: const Text("Favorite Animals"),
        items: _items,
        searchable: true,
        validator: (values) {
          if (values == null || values.isEmpty) {
            return "Required";
          }
          List<String> names = values.map((e) => e.name).toList(); // Update here
          if (names.contains("Frog")) {
            return "Frogs are weird!";
          }
          return null;
        },
        onConfirm: (List<Animal> values) {
          // Update here
          setState(() {
            _selectedAnimals3 = values;
          });
          _multiSelectKey.currentState?.validate();
        },
        chipDisplay: MultiSelectChipDisplay(
          onTap: (item) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedAnimals3.remove(item);
            });
            _multiSelectKey.currentState?.validate();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. I confirm it works when making MultiSelectBottomSheetField<Animal?> type parameter as nullable. 
Would you be able to suggest another library which offers multiselect dropdown with search functionality out of the box ?

Comment: I forked the library, and changed to solve the `null safety`. Please review my changes in answer. You can either use my fork or fork from my repo for your usage.

Comment: Thanks Alex for fixing the issue in the original library. I switched to yours and updated my code as per your suggestion in "Edited" part and it all works as expected. Good job !

Comment: I hope this answer could be  accepted .